# Array of strings of unknown size inside array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I create an array like this in javascript:

```
var cells_content = [["car", "house", "pet"], ["fast", "car"], ["jupiter", "is", "a", "big", "planet", "really", "big"]]
```

I'm assuming I would declare the variable as:

```
var cells_content = new Array();
```

But then how would I add the content to the array and how would I retrieve it?

Comment: Objects should be key:value pairs, you want an array of arrays.

Comment: Expressions like `{"car", "house", "pet"}` aren't actually very interesting in JavaScript. That one, for example, evaluates to `"pet"`. What are you trying to do with those expressions?

Comment: @murgatroid99: That's no expression, but a syntax error?

Comment: @Bergi When I run it in a Chrome console, I get what I described, so it's not a syntax error. I think it's some sort of block

Comment: When you run it as a statement then yes, it will become a block with a comma expression statement. Used as an expression (e.g. in an array literal as the OP has it) it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of objects you placed inside the array is not valid. If you want an array of arrays, like this:

```
var cells_content = [["car", "house", "pet"], ["fast", "car"], ["jupiter", "is", "a", "big", "planet", "really", "big"]]
```

In order to do this, you can "push" arrays inside the main array, as well as strings inside the inner arrays.

```
cells_content.push(["car", "house", "pet"]);
```

To retreive an inner array, you do this:

```
cells_content[0] // get the first inner array
cells_content[0].push("red"); // will add "red" to the first inner array
```

Answer (score 2):

I like doing this:

```
var multidimArray = [[],[]];
```

and then for all the extra arrays i want to append after that I do this:

```
array = [];
for(c = 0; c < x.length; c++){
   array.push(x[c]);
}
multidimArray.push(array)
```

alternatively you could just append [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) Objects to the array

Answer (score 1):

An array of arrays is defined like this:

```
var cells_content = [["car","house","pet"],["fast","car"]];
```

and accessed like this:

`cells_content[i][j]`

```
s = cells_content[0][1]; // "house"

s = cells_content[1][0]; // "fast"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your objects should contain key:value pairs, I believe you actually want an array of arrays. One way to achieve this would be:

```
var cells_content = new Array();

var content = ["car", "house", "pet"];

cells_content.push(content);
console.log(cells_content[0]);
```